# M2 - Variables empty in CMS Pages

Tags: cms-pages, variables

No matter if System Variable or from the STORES > CONFIGURATION > Store Information fields, I can not output variables in cms pages. It feels like I'm missing something so basic, that I can not even google a similar problem.

I've tried to use the INSERT VARIABLE button in wysiwyg mode and in plain text, also custom variables, but I get no output.

It is also not a problem of Store View Mode, deleted cache, reindexed everything, tried production mode and developer mode, all logs are empty (or at least show now errors related to it)

It is also strange, that it works If I put the code below into a Block and then include this block into my cms page.

Is it a security thing, which I do not understand?

Magento 2.3.2

My Plain HTML Code of my cms page, which only outputs "1 2":

```
1 
{{config path="system/config/path"}} 
{{config path="general/store_information/city"}}
{{customVar code=testvar}}
2
```